# JQuery Mobile without injected elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a web app that requires touch for tablet users. I have been trying out JQuery Mobile. However JQuery Mobile seems to be wrapping my content with it's own page elements.

Is it possible to stop JQuery Mobile from doing this? I would prefer it if the HTML page is unchanged.

I have been having a look at JQuery Mobile Initialization though I can't see how this can be changed.

All I need from JQuery Mobile is the touch events. So if JQuery Mobile cannot be changed is there a simpler alternative?

Thanks,

Comment: it's useless to use jQM just for touch events. you can go to download section and use builder to build a custom jQM version. Or just use a third party touch events library.

Comment: @Frederic This is not a duplicate. I have read the other post and tried two solutions and they do nothing to prevent jQM from injecting page elements and scripts into the page. My question is clearly totally different.

Comment: @Funky, I might have misunderstood your question, but jQuery Mobile definitely does not inject scripts, and will only enhance your markup if you do not apply `data-role="none"`, as said in the duplicate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi jQuery mobile was definitely wrapping all the content inside the body element with it's own div and injecting other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery mobile is too comprehensive to just accomplish what you are trying. Take a look at Hammer JS as alternative:

http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Comment: Thanks Wimpie! I'm going for the hammer jQuery plugin at the moment. Haven't had a chance to test it properly yet though.